# Node.js chat app with username variables not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I'm making a chat app in node.js based on a tutorial from socket.io. The purpose is for a user to enter in a username and a message. The chat will display "username: message". The username text field will then disappear after the first entry. I have it all working except for the chat displaying the message with the username. The chat displays four messages instead of one, they say that both variables are undefined.

JS

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg, usn){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
    io.emit('chat message', usn);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

HTML (Without the style tags)

```
<!doctype html>


<html>


  <head>

    <title>Lucas Chat</title>



  </head>



  <body>

    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="u" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nickname"/><input id="m" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Message"/><button>Send</button>
    </form>



      <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#u').val());
        $('#u').css("display", "none")
        $('#m').css("width", "90%")
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg, usn){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(usn + ": " + msg));
      });
    </script>



  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clientside

```
var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('send message', {msg:$('#m').val(),user:$('#u').val()});
    $('#u').css("display", "none")
    $('#m').css("width", "90%")
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('receive message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
```

and serverside

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('send message', function(data){
    io.emit('receive message',data.msg + ':' + data.user);
  });
});
```